# Split a string to a map

Tags: java, regex, string, dictionary, split

I have following string:

```
...
field [
name = marked
value = false
]
field [
name = currenFolder
value = null
]
...
```

which is basically an object saved this way in a database. I now want to create back a map of this two fields (unsure if that's the best solution, but anyway ;-). Some advice would be great! The map should have as key marked, as value false etc.. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please tag the question with what programming language you are using.

Comment: Think you should serialize that object to a json string and save it, then you can restore that string to a hash type

Comment: Thanks. But its not the question how to save rather then how to recreate from saved data a map. I guess regex would do the trick. For example with split("field") which is a start but i am just missing the idea. Hint?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess regex would do the trick.

If you utilize [`regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-frame.html), you can use [Capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) to extract *name* and *value*:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class map
{ 
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        String string = "...\nfield [\nname = marked\nvalue = false\n]\n"
                      + "field [\nname = currenFolder\nvalue = null\n]\n...\n";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("field .(?s).name = (.*?).value = (.*?).]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
        while (m.find())
            map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```